# Backup mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, backup

Is there a way using PHP to make a backup of data only from MySQL database tables?

Comment: This is of course possible. That said, can you execute the standard `mysqldump` command within your operating environment? (It'll be a *lot* less hassle if you can use this approach.)

Comment: I can, but mysqldump takes the structure as well - doesn't it?

Comment: @user398341 So you *just* want the raw data (e.g.: as CSV) rather than any form of `INSERT` statements, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php and remove the parts where he generates sql commands for re-creating the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SHOW TABLES` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) to get each table, loop them with PHP using `SELECT * FROM -tablename-`. Then loop this record set, use `implode(',' $results)` to get the data (CSV). You might want to create a seperate for or something for each table of course.

Answer (score 0):

You agree that you want "want the raw data (e.g.: as CSV) rather than any form of INSERT statements" - but the answer you've accepted does precisely the latter, using e.g. this line of code:

```
$return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
```

Which is fine if that's really what you want, but if I were you I would then just make a system call to mysqldump instead. You can get mysqldump to just generate a set of INSERT INTO statements in a safe, robust way without worrying about "did I close that double quote? Should there be an extra comma here?" etc.

I don't know why you don't want to export the schema as well - if you specify --add-drop-table then your database dump becomes a nice, neat restore of your whole db if the worst happens - but if you just want to export your data, and you can make a system call to mysqldump in your PHP script, [you could run](http://chriswa.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/mysqldump-data-only/):

```
mysqldump --skip-triggers --compact --no-create-info db_name | gzip -c > /tmp/db_name_backup.sql.gz
```

--no-create-info excludes all the CREATE TABLE statements; but as I say, I would rather include both CREATE and DROP IF EXISTS, so you have a complete backup of data and schema.

I really recommend backing up using mysqldump's generated SQL - which MySQL innately understands, and which handles encoding, whitespace etc. properly - rather than something like CSV - which AFAIK isn't actually any kind of internationally recognized standard, and can't be piped back into mysql to restore your database at a later date:

```
gunzip -c < /tmp/db_name_backup.sql.gz | mysql db_name
```

If your backup was instead a separate CSV file for every single table, restoring that backup becomes a far more difficult task.

Comment: Can I have it done without compression? Also - I'm using PDO - any example how should I do it with it?

Comment: Another problem is relationships - when restoring - the relationship between the tables can cause problems if commands aren't executed in the right order - therefore manual backup gives me a bit more control over how to back it up and what order of the tables to use. is there an option to put all ALTER statements with FOREIGN KEYS at the end of the file?

Comment: And sorry - by raw data I mean - sql statements which contain only data - without database structure - so it would include INSERT statements.

Comment: By calling mysqldump this is what I get: Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help

Comment: None of these are problems with mysqldump. It dumps out fine for table restoring. If you're getting those options then you're not running mysqldump with the db_name I specified. If you don't want it to compress, then you can just omit the gzip / gunzip stages, but if it's a big database then I wouldn't recommend that as you might as well always compress dumps.